# Can you tell me if this is broken ? Jquery UI .soretable() "sortout' not firing until "sortreceive" fires

Tags: jquery, events, drag, portlet, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm expecting "sortout' event to fire when the dragging portal leaves the column. The 'sortover' event fires as expected.. I'm not sure if this is the way it should work or jquery UI is broken.

Here is the demo code http://jsfiddle.net/kY7SV/6/  Drag all the portlets out of the column and it should collapse. Drag portlets over the collapsed column, and it should expand.

Help is appreciated

Edit for Merlyn the important bits:

```
<ul id="sm" class="sm">
    <li id=list1><div style="background-color:red">1</div>
        <div class="column" id='col1'>
            <div class="portlet">
                <div class="portlet-header">Feeds</div>
                <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
            <div class="portlet">
                <div class="portlet-header">News</div>
                <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id=list2><div style="background-color:yellow">2</div>
        <div class="column" id='col2'>
            <div class="portlet">
                <div class="portlet-header">Shopping</div>
                <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
            <div class="portlet">
                <div class="portlet-header">Messages</div>
                <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id=list3><div style="background-color:blue">3</div>
        <div class="column" id='col3'>
            <div class="portlet">
                <div class="portlet-header">Links</div>
                <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
            <div class="portlet">
                <div class="portlet-header">iMAGES</div>
                <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
​
$(function() {
    $(".column").sortable({
        connectWith: ".column"
    });

    $(".portlet").addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all").find(".portlet-header").addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all").prepend("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>").end().find(".portlet-content");

    $(".portlet-header .ui-icon").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick").toggleClass("ui-icon-plusthick");
        $(this).parents(".portlet:first").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
    });

    $(".column").disableSelection();

    $(".column").bind("sortremove", function(event, ui) {
        var listitem = $(this).parents('li');
        var cnt = $(this).children().length;
        if (cnt < 1) {
            $(listitem).css('maxWidth', '25px');
        }
    });

    $(".column").bind("sortover", function(event, ui) {
        var listitem = $(this).parents('li');
        $(listitem).css('maxWidth', '');
    });

    $(".column").bind("sortout", function(event, ui) {
        var listitem = $(this).parents('li');
        var cnt = $(this).children().length;
        if (cnt < 1) {
            $(listitem).css('maxWidth', '25px');
        }
    });

    $(".column").bind("sortreceive", function(event, ui) {
        var listitem = $(this).parents('li');
        $(listitem).css('maxWidth', '');
    });

});​
```

Comment: Feel free to keep the jsfiddle link, but please add at least your JS code directly to the question.  SO questions should be self-contained whenever possible, and should only rely on third party sites for ease of use.

Comment: Hi Merlyn NP, I just thought it would be easier to use live code to see it work.

Comment: Also NP.  Including the jsfiddle is really helpful to people answering your question.  Including the code in the question is the most important part, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem

The problem is that you're selecting the wrong items.  The `li` always contains exactly two children: The text `div`, and the container `div`.  It doesn't directly contain your items.

`ui.sender` seems to give the source `li` directly, though.  You could call `$(ui.sender).children().count` to get the count of the column you are dragging out of.

The child count during the `out` event will always be `1` or more while doing the drag, and only when the drop fires will the count be `0`.  This probably has to do with the timing of when the event fires, or the fact that it might leave some sort of placeholder element while doing the dragging.

#### Suggested Solution

I recommend rethinking the demo, at least in regards to the `out` event.  It is tricky logic to determine when you're *still dragging* and when you've *finished* dragging from inside that `out` event.  It also is good UI design to leave a large drop-target while you're dragging things around.

The `remove` and `receive` events have a much more obvious count.  I'd stick with resizing on those events.

#### How I figured this out

I opened my javascript console (F12 in your browser), and inserted a console write statement inside the `out` event.  On chrome, this is `console.out(...item to log here...)`.  I toyed around with the various objects available to me (`this`, `event`, `ui`), and checked the `outerHTML` on their various HTML element properties.

Once you figured out how to select the right element, a simple way to figure out the count part of the problem would be to update the text of an element with the current child count.  Then you'd see it update in real-time, per-column.  I was logging, and noticed it was permanently stuck at `2`, which clued me in to the fact that the wrong element was selected.

#### Notes

I can't figure out what all the properties on `this` are supposed to be, and they seemed to change over time.  [The documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-out) isn't much help.  If I knew more about javascript events (in general) that might have helped me figure it out :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I'm not selecting LI for the count, I'm getting the correct instance of column. The problem I'm seeing is: the sortout event does not fire until the drop when

Comment: @garyM: That's true, you're using `this` - I got a little confused through all the mucking around with objects I was doing :)  The count logic is still broken though, and will never go below 1.  Try doing a `console.log(cnt)` to check it out.  The event fires all the time, which logging out to the javascript console will show you.  You could throw an `assert('test');` inside the event to test it too.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I'm not selecting LI for the sortable events. You are right about the LI on the counts. 

But your suggestion lead  me into a better diagnosis. The problem is I'm not seeing any "sortout" until the drop. And, the 'sortout' is the wrong item, it fires for the drop target. 

According to the doc, the events are associated with the bind object ".column".  

This is what I'm seeing:

Comment: 1) The column1 "sortout" event does not fire on the drag out.
2) The column1 "sortremove" event does fire
3) The column2 "sortout" event then fires with the column drop target
4) The column2 "sortreceive" fires 

It seems the "sortout" event is just not firing.

Comment: I'm fighting with the "add comments" --- sorry for the confusing replys

Comment: Fixed the 'li' count:  [link]http://jsfiddle.net/kY7SV/9/  Still no drag out event. I'm thinking its broken.

Comment: @garyM: Maybe it's your browser then, or a bug specific to your browser?  I'm using chrome, and I'm seeing the event fire.  Not very often, and only when you're dragging it around like crazy onto the other columns (without dropping).  It also doesn't fire when you try to drag it anywhere around the page but on top of other lists.  But it is definitely firing.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on chrome, FF11, IE9. I removed the list (lu/li), changed the tolerance to "mouse", changed the distance values, etc.. this just doesn't work as advertised.  It should fire as the drag leaves the column.. and it doesn't.

Comment: **IT'S A BUG OPEN FOR TWO YEARS !!!**
Ticket #5671  [link]http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5671  There is a link to the _fix_ posted, but the link is dead.

Comment: You should post that as an answer to your own question.  It's allowed and encouraged.  Good find.